# FeedWordPress not parsing images properly

Tags: wordpress, plugins, feedparser

I recently installed WordPress and have been slowly learning how to use it. I've tried to solve this one problem for about an hour now, and I can't seem to find the problem.

No matter what feed I add to `FeedWordPress`, it just doesn't parse the images correctly. (But it does, see here): http://ttgdark.com/

It's like it's completely remove the path to the image in the src tag.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: i think u have some problem with the plugin.. try reading the installations and how to's of the plugin  timthumb that you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to you source code find this:

```
<img src="http://ttgdark.com/wp-content/themes/Webly/timthumb.php?
 http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/ThatVideogameBlog/~4/PkjR8RbxWzQ
 &amp;h=200&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1&amp;q=90" class="post-thumb">
```

and remove this line of code

```
http://ttgdark.com/wp-content/themes/Webly/timthumb.php?src=
```

it should help.

Comment: I wasn't able to remove that line of code, but I was able to modify that file to work properly. Thanks!